Can't find the right function
all I need is to inject my function instead of playfab connection to official server using minhook
mb no need in full dump but can't identify correctly name of "login to playfab" function
I found this classes
[003959] Enum Backend.EYLoginResult
[003960] Enum YOnlineSubsystemUtilsPlugin.EYPlayfabLoginType
[003961] Enum YOnlineSubsystemUtilsPlugin.EYAuthorizationUsageType

and this
00000001448D7AD0  4F 6E 50 6C 61 79 66 61  62 53 65 72 76 65 72 4C  OnPlayfabServerL
00000001448D7AE0  6F 67 69 6E 00 00 00 00  40 70 D0 45 01 00 00 00  ogin....@p......
00000001448D7AF0  78 70 D0 45 01 00 00 00  A0 70 D0 45 01 00 00 00  xp.......p......
00000001448D7B00  73 75 63 63 65 64 65 64  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  succeded........
00000001448D7B10  6C 6F 67 69 6E 45 72 72  6F 72 00 00 00 00 00 00  loginError......
00000001448D7B20  70 6C 61 79 66 61 62 54  69 74 6C 65 49 64 00 00  playfabTitleId..

and this
.rdata:00000001448D7AD0 aOnplayfabserve db 'OnPlayfabServerLogin',0
.rdata:00000001448D7AD0                                         ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00000001448D7B48↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7AD0                                         ; .rdata:00000001448D8730↓o ...
.rdata:00000001448D7AE5                 align 8
.rdata:00000001448D7AE8 off_1448D7AE8   dq offset off_145D07040 ; DATA XREF: .data:0000000145D07100↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7AE8                                         ; "succeded"
.rdata:00000001448D7AF0                 dq offset off_145D07078 ; "loginError"
.rdata:00000001448D7AF8                 dq offset off_145D070A0 ; "playfabTitleId"
.rdata:00000001448D7B00 aSucceded       db 'succeded',0         ; DATA XREF: .data:off_145D07040↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B00                                         ; .data:off_145D31128↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B09                 align 10h
.rdata:00000001448D7B10 aLoginerror     db 'loginError',0       ; DATA XREF: .data:off_145D07078↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B10                                         ; .data:off_145D31160↓o ...
.rdata:00000001448D7B1B                 align 20h
.rdata:00000001448D7B20 aPlayfabtitleid db 'playfabTitleId',0   ; DATA XREF: .data:off_145D070A0↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B20                                         ; .data:off_145D31188↓o ...
.rdata:00000001448D7B2F                 align 10h
.rdata:00000001448D7B30 off_1448D7B30   dq offset qword_1421F3A90+130h
.rdata:00000001448D7B30                                         ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00000001448D7B78↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B38                 dq offset qword_140946A90+6A0h
.rdata:00000001448D7B40 off_1448D7B40   dq offset qword_140946A90+440h
.rdata:00000001448D7B40                                         ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00000001448D7B80↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B48                 dq offset aOnplayfabserve ; "OnPlayfabServerLogin"
.rdata:00000001448D7B50 off_1448D7B50   dq offset off_145D07118 ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00000001448D7B88↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B50                                         ; "m_playfabInstance"
.rdata:00000001448D7B58 unk_1448D7B58   db    0                 ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00000001448D7B70↓o
.rdata:00000001448D7B59                 db    0

tried to implement it here
Function offset, find with "?sdk=".*/
constexpr uintptr_t OffsetOnPlayfabServerLogin = 0x140965CF0;

/**
 
Function hooks.*/
typedef SDK::FString(fastcall* tOnPlayfabServerLogin)(SDK::YPlayFabAPISettings*, const SDK::FString&);

tOnPlayfabServerLogin OldOnPlayfabServerLogin;

SDK::FString fastcall OnPlayfabServerLoginProxy(SDK::YPlayFabAPISettings* thiz, const SDK::FString& callPath)
{
    logger::Print("[Agent] GetURL called with callPath %s\n", callPath.ToString().c_str());

    return std::wstring(L"http://127.0.0.1:5000") + std::wstring(callPath.c_str());
}

but failed
